# Vagrant/Homestead Set up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am setting up Vagrant/Homestead on a Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed VirtualBox, Vagrant, Composer, and PHP.

I downloaded Homestead from the git repository

git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead

I cd into the Homestead directory

Ran

bash init.sh

Received the message Homestead initialized!

but when I navigate to cd .homestead I get an error message that says

bash: cd: .homestead: No such file or directory

I also tried cd ~/.homestead still received the bash: cd: .homestead: No such file or directory

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?  I provided the terminal commands and results of each command.

```
font@font-Linux:~$ cd web
font@font-Linux:~/web$ cd ..
font@font-Linux:~$ vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL:removed the url for posting purposes
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) hyperv
2) parallels
3) virtualbox
4) vmware_desktop

Enter your choice: 3
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/2.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'laravel/homestead' (v2.1.0) for 'virtualbox'!
font@font-Linux:~$ cd web
font@font-Linux:~/web$ git clone command removed the link for posting purposes //github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
Cloning into 'Homestead'...
remote: Counting objects: 2184, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 2184 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2180
Receiving objects: 100% (2184/2184), 383.40 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1266/1266), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
font@font-Linux:~/web$ cd Homestead
font@font-Linux:~/web/Homestead$ bash init.sh
Homestead initialized!
font@font-Linux:~/web/Homestead$ cd ..
font@font-Linux:~/web$ cd ..
font@font-Linux:~$ cd .homestead
bash: cd: .homestead: No such file or directory
font@font-Linux:~$ cd ~/Homestead
bash: cd: /home/font/Homestead: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of Homestead require homestead.yaml to be in ~/Homestead directory you created when you cloned the repo.
You don't need ".homestead" folder.

In your case, you created it in ~/web/Homestead.
so, cd into  ~/web/Homestead and vagrant up.

Answer (score 0):

Now, Homestead version was created Homestead(H uppercase) folder, you need `cd ~/Homestead` and `vagrant up`

Comment: I also tried with a Uppercase H but still no luck.  Provided my terminal commands up top.

Comment: Could you vagrant up now?